# Create chat balloon with JS HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, simple-html-dom

I am about to make a chat balloon that pops up, when the user is on the page.
My "balloon" now doesn't look like a chat balloon.

It should look like this:
[Chat Balloon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2taSQ.png)

I don't know how to make that thing under the balloon with HTML DOM.

How I'm able to do that with JS HTML DOM?

I already got this:

```js
this.div = document.createElement('div');
// set style of div
this.div.style.width = '120px';
this.div.style.height = '46px';
this.div.style.bottom = '30%';
this.div.style.zIndex = '9999999';
this.div.style.display = 'block';
this.div.style.position = 'fixed';
this.div.style.bottom = '12%';
this.div.style.paddingTop = '8px';
this.div.style.color = 'black';
this.div.style.right = '1%';
this.div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(211, 211, 211, 1)';
this.div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
this.div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
this.div.style.textAlign = 'center';
this.div.style.borderRadius = "6px";
this.div.style.borderColor = 'lightgray';
this.div.setAttribute("id", "help");
document.body.appendChild(this.div);
document.getElementById("help").innerHTML = "Kan ik u helpen?";
```

Could someone give me information on how to do this or do this for me?
I prefer to edit my snippet.
You can give me examples too.

Comment: This will help you: https://css-tricks.com/replicating-google-hangouts-chat/

Comment: Try that one also: https://codepen.io/Founts/pen/gmhcl

Comment: No thats not what I meant!

Comment: I need to make this in HTML DOM JS

Comment: @MarioPolio why js only ? Since this applies for all bubbles, it's best to use CSS rules and simply assign classes when adding bubbles

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example like the image you lined. You can view a working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/oL5bc1j4/

HTML:

```
<div class="bubble">CSS Speech Bubble</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bubble 
{
position: relative;
width: 250px;
height: 120px;
padding: 0px;
background: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: #7F7F7F solid 5px;
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 26px 15px 0;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
bottom: -26px;
left: 35px;
}

.bubble:before 
{
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 30px 19px 0;
border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
bottom: -35px;
left: 31px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/oL5bc1j4/

Comment: Yeah, but I need to do this in HTML DOM JS.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to insert the chat bubble using javascript?

Comment: If so, still add the css to your stylesheets, and use JS to insert `<div class="bubble">CSS Speech Bubble</div>` where needed